# What goes in ~/.bash_profile and what goes in ~/.bashrc?

Tags: bash

If bash is my shell, what should I put in `~/.bash_profile` and what should I put in `~/.bashrc`?

My understanding is that `~/.bash_profile` is read on login, and `~/.bashrc` is read for each new interactive non-login shell. I can set `~/.bash_profile` to read `~/.bashrc` if I want.

But since I can't actually think of anything that I don't want to always be set to some initial value, and since every Unix process (not only the shell) inherits the environment variables of its parent process, why wouldn't I just put everything into `~/.bash_profile` and just forget about `~/.bashrc`? What is the rationale for setting things again and again to the same value every time `~/.bashrc` is read, when they could just be set once initially in `~/.bash_profile`?

Or maybe what I'm really asking is what *logically* goes into each of `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`, irrespective of my own requirements.

(I fully admit ignorance, and I'd also gladly be corrected on the above if my understanding is incorrect.)

Comment: I've found a related question: [Why have both .bash_profile and .bashrc?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/346336) but it doesn't really explain the rationale of `.bashrc` to me. The answer over there says of `.bashrc`, "_aliases, functions, etc [...] are per shell session items that are not inherited from environment._" Well, aren't they inherited from the environment?

Comment: No, those things (aliases, functions, etc.) that are not inherited from the environment are indeed not inherited from the environment.

Comment: Once upon a time, room in the environment was at a premium. You wouldn't want it cluttered with interactive-shell specific things like `PS1` that no other process would care about.